# how to implement filters in elasticsearch using nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Assume I get some list of products after I search for the same, now I want to filter them based on say colour, size, etc. attributes.

How can I write nested queries?

Here's my search query:

```
   var result = client.Search<document>(s => s
                    .Analyzer("automplete").From(0).Size(20)
                    .Query(p => p
                        .MultiMatch(m => m
                            .OnFields(new[] { svalue })
                            .Query(value).Type(TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix)))
                            .Highlight(m => m.OnFields(n => n.OnField("some_field"))));
```

Comment: @bittusarkar can you help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope you are fine
I think that you are traying to find in nested objets. Elasticsearch have a speacil query for this needs is the [NestedQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html)

`

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title": "eggs" }}, 
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ 
                  { "match": { "comments.name": "john" }},
                  { "match": { "comments.age":  28     }}
                ]
        }}}}
      ]
}}}
```

`

In you case, to access nested objet you should need add products.color for the criteria.

Comment: am not sure how to do that in nest